# Align order of text labels with sorted stacked bar segments

Tags: python, colors, bar-chart, visualization, altair

I am trying to add text to this chart.
[image]

I used this code, **the text is in its right order** but **the color of it is changeable** according to the color of respective bar so when I bar+text, the text is invisible
[image: ![coloful text]

People told me it is because *"Colors specified in encodings take priority over colors specified in mark properties"* so I should make a base chart without colors and build text based on that base chart like this: [image]

Now **the text is black but displayed in wrong order**. I think the problem is I only can order my bars as I want (Paid work first, then Education, Sleep...) by colors. So if I want my text black by not coloring my bars in the base chart, I lose the order I want.
[image]

Is there any way I can make the text black while keeping it in the right order? (Paid work first, then Education, Sleep, so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the color encoding to specify the sort order and since this will override any color set inside `mark_text`, you will also need to set the range of the text color encoding to only include black. Resolving the color scale makes sure that only the text is colored black. I don't think there is a way to center the text horizontally within each bar segment.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

site_order = ['Duluth', 'Crookston', 'Waseca', 'University Farm', 'Grand Rapids', 'Morris']
bars = alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield)',
    y='variety',
    color=alt.Color('site', sort=site_order),
    order=alt.Order('color_site_sort_index:Q'))

text = bars.mark_text(align='right', dx=-2).encode(
    x=alt.X('sum(yield):Q', stack=True),
    color=alt.Color('site', sort=site_order, scale=alt.Scale(range=['black']), legend=None),
    text=alt.Text('sum(yield):Q', format='.1f'))

(bars + text).resolve_scale(color='independent')
```

[image]

Comment: Woh awesome, thank you so much @joelostblom for helping me again.

Answer (score 1):

Put `color=alt.value('black')` in the encode instead of the mark, or don't inherit from base chart for your text mark.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, *"Colors specified in encodings take priority over colors specified in mark properties"*. That is detailed in the documentation here: [Global Config vs. Local Config vs. Encoding](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#global-config-vs-local-config-vs-encoding).

Your solution of removing the color from the base chart is correct: the issue is you also removed the order which (naturally) makes it so that the text no longer has the same order. Remove the color from the base chart but keep the order and it should work.

Alternatively, you can override the encoding in the text chart by using

```py
chart.encode(
  color=alt.value('black')
)
```

Comment: I tried both but they dont work. (1) I kept the order in the base chart with ( order=alt.Order('color_Category_sort_index:Q') ) and the text order is wrong (Alphabetical order instead of the order I want) (2) I tried your recommended code before, no need a base chart but it generated the same wrong order of text also

Comment: If you're referring to the sort order of the y labels on the layered axis, this is a known issue: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1371 You can work around it by setting `resolve_scale(y='independent')` or `resolve_scale(color='independent')` (it's not clear to me whether the order you're concerned with is the y-axis or the color legend).

Comment: The color legend I mean, I would like the text and the legend to be in this order (paid work, education, sleep,... ) please see my very first picture on the question, I define the order I want in an array named CatOrder before. My problem is that the category (legend) is in Catorder (what I want) but the text is in alphabetical order instead.

Comment: Sorry, this is getting a bit complicated to follow. Since your main question here (how to display black text on colored bars) has been answered, perhaps you can ask a new question about order, and please in the future avoid screenshots of code, and instead paste the code itself so that it can be copied and pasted as text.

Comment: Hey I am sorry, will be more careful next time. Thank you for your support