# Sort a stacked bar chart with transform fold Altair

Tags: python, altair

I was wondering if there is any way to sort the bars within a stacked bar chart when the chart contains a transform fold. My data is "wide form":

[image]

and I want each row of the dataframe to be represented with its own bar in a chart. Hence, I need to first do a transform fold. This all works fine and the bars appear to be sorted alphabetically by default. HOWEVER, let's say I want the order of the bars within the stacked bar to be different from the way they are displaying by default.

I have tried:

- changing the order of the columns within the transform_fold
- adding a sort parameter within the X axis definition (both `None` so that it ignores the alphabetical default sort and the explicit ordered list as shown in the code below)
- adding an order field
- adding a sort parameter within the color definition

None of these approaches seem to make any difference from the default alphabetical sort! Is there a special way to do this when you have a transform fold?

Minimal code (with all attempts at ordering added) and output here:

```
small_df = pd.DataFrame({'Probability A':[0.2,0.8,0.4],'Probability B':[0.5,0.1,0.1],'Probability C':[0.3,0.1,0.5],'ID':['John','Sally','Frank']})

alt.Chart(small_df).mark_bar().transform_fold(
        ['Probability A','Probability C','Probability B']
    ).encode(
        x=alt.X('value:Q',scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 1]),sort=['Probability A','Probability C','Probability B']),
        y='ID:N',
        order=['Probability A','Probability C','Probability B'],
        color=alt.Color('key:N',sort=['Probability A','Probability C','Probability B'],scale=alt.Scale(domain=['Probability A','Probability B','Probability C'],range=['red', 'orange', 'green']))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused with all the different settings. Let me try to break this down.

1. The order of the color legend can be controlled using the `scale` argument.

```
alt.Chart(small_df).mark_bar().transform_fold(
        ['Probability A','Probability B','Probability C']
    ).encode(
        x=alt.X('value:Q',scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 1])),
        y='ID:N',
        color=alt.Color('key:N',
            # arrange the column-colr pairs to you what you want
            scale=alt.Scale(
                domain=['Probability C','Probability A','Probability B'],
                range=['red', 'orange', 'green']
            )
        ),
        #order=alt.Order('value:Q',sort='descending'),
        #order=alt.Order('key:N',sort='descending'),
)
```

[image]

2. To control the order of the columns inside each horizontal bar, we use `order` argument. By default, the columns are in ascending order in each bar. In the above code, if you uncomment the line

```
order=alt.Order('key:N',sort='descending'),
```

This will give you the column in descending order of `key` i.e., your column.

[image]

You can also use other ways of ordering it. For example, if you want it according to the `value` variable, uncomment the line

```
order=alt.Order('value:Q',sort='descending'),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes, definitely confused with all of the settings so thank you for clearing them up. I am still hoping to get a solution similar to 2 - where the order of the columns within the horizontal bars are updated, however I would like it to be ordered by an explicit list rather than by 'ascending' or 'descending' on the names (my use case is neither alphabetical or reverse alphabetical on the names but rather ['A', 'C', 'B'], for instance) is there a way to do this?

Comment: I do realize that I can simply change the headers to begin with 'A', 'B', 'C' and that would sort them appropriately (if there is no other solution to hard-coded sortings)

Comment: You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347857/sort-a-normalized-stacked-bar-chart-with-altair) thread.

Comment: Nice! For some reason I thought that wouldn't apply to a Fold Transform, but adding ```order='color_value_sort_index:Q'``` reflects whatever the ordering of the items in the transform are. Thanks a ton!